# Is it possible to display a specific block from a template in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls, django-template-filters

Just like in html when you reference a section of a page with for instance`<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>`
Would there be a way to do a similar thing in django if for instance I wanted to load my page straight to the tips section? I am extending base.html to my home page that has a tips section. Right now i have a static url `<a href="some url/#tips">home</a>` i want to do the exact same but with djangos dynamic url something like `{% url 'home'/#tips %}`

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: The browser does not even see template blocks, because the template is rendered before it is sent to the browser. If you need to scroll to a particular place, use an anchor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django redirect() with anchor (#) parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165267/django-redirect-with-anchor-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) right after the URL returned by the `{% url %}` template tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}#tips">home</a>
```