# Django render with anchor

Tags: django

I would like to return to a particular web page location (jump to in-page anchor) after reading the view. In other words, in views.py, I would like to do something like:

```
context={'form':my_form}
return render(request, 'my_app/my_page.html/#my_anchor', context)
```

However, I need a file path and not an url.

I am aware I can do this with 'redirect' ([Django redirect() with anchor (#) parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165267/django-redirect-with-anchor-parameters)) but I need to return the context form. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

It doesn't make sense to include the anchor in the template. The template is the name of the template file on the disk that is being rendered, it is completely separate from the url.

You could add your anchor to the template context.

```
context['anchor'] = 'my_anchor'
return render(request, 'my_app/my_page.html, context)
```

Then in your template, you can change the location to the anchor using javascript. Assuming you are using jQuery, you could do:

```
{% if anchor %}
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.location = '#{{ anchor }}'
});
</script>
{% endif %}
```

I would be wary of doing this if the anchor comes from user input. You don't want a malicious user to be able to redirect you to a different domain. I think that hardcoding '#' in the template should prevent the browser being redirected to a different domain, but I am not certain.

Comment: JS is the only way to accomplish this eh (in this particular scenario)?

Comment: You can redirect to the url with an anchor, but the OP said they couldn’t do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a generic solution, but if the purpose is to scroll the webpage down to the form you just submitted (after form validation for example), you can put the anchor reference in the `action` attribute of the form:

```
<div id="my-anchor">
    {% if success %}
        <!-- Success message -->
    {% else %}
        <form method="post" action="#my-anchor">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <!-- Form inputs -->
        </form>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

This works in any browser.