# Remove anchor name from Django HttpResponseRedirect or redirect

Tags: django, redirect

I don't know if it's a bug or a feature, but when I'm on my home page with the contact form anchor
(url = `http://localhost:8000/#contact`)

After submitting the form, all of these will redirect including the `#contact` anchor name and I cannot get rid of it:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# Following 3 lines all send back to http://localhost:8000/#contact
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage'))
return redirect(reverse('homepage'))
return redirect('/')

# As a test, the following line redirects to http://localhost:8000/account/email/#contact
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:email'))
```

I found some people with the opposite issue, trying to [add the anchor name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165267/django-redirect-with-anchor-parameters), but can't find a related question with my issue

Comment: use the name of he path you want to redirect to and use it in the redirect function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser preserves a fragment during redirect, you can check out these SO questions/answers:

1. [URL hash is persisting between redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283395/url-hash-is-persisting-between-redirects)
2. [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)

So, I believe you could try setting an empty fragment in the redirect URL to override page's URL fragment. If it doesn't help then redirect from JS on a successful response.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Should have searched for a broader solution I guess