# How to append string in the end of Django redirect in view?

Tags: django

I have a product on my platform and when a specific user does an action, I want to redirect them to example.com/product/product-slug/#SectionInWebsite.

However, I am not able to find a way to append "#SectionInWebsite" to the end of the redirect function.

```
return redirect('ProductSingle', product.slug, "#SectionInWebsite")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (I had to use different names on my machine, but it should work):

```py
# views.py
return redirect('{}#sectionInWebsite'.format(reverse('ProductSingle', kwargs={'product_slug':product.slug})))
```

That is, assuming your **urls.py** has something like this:

```py
# urls.py
...
path('ProductSingle/<str:product_slug>', views.ProductSingle, name='ProductSingle'),
...
```

This is just a variation of the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166850/10951070), applied to your situation.

Comment: This would indeed work with JS and I am aware of this solution, but the problem is that when users want to just access the page without taking the action that is supposed to send them to #SectionInWebsite, they will still get redirected there. So unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Got it.  Will delete answer and investigate further @DjAndGo

Comment: I tried this on my machine, @DjAndGo and it seems to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you, using reverse.

```
return redirect(reverse('ProductSingle', product.slug) + '#SectionInWebsite')
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.
`bad operand type for unary +: 'str'`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to close parentheses, already edited :)

Answer (score 1):

do this :

```
return redirect(reverse('ProductSingle',product.slug) + '#SectionInWebsite')
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( 

`No module named 'product-slug'`